# launch many querys at one button click but in correct order so the second query will wait until the first is complete etc

Tags: swift, parsing

I'm doing many queries from parse at 1 button click but i need to queue them so that when the first one is complete the second one Begins etc. I guess I have to use completions but I can't figure it out how to use after a Query.
I would really appreciate help guys =)! btw I am new to programming just started 2 months ago.

To explain more specific I am creating a login page where you can login and see friendrequests and add friends.
so when I push login button I want the login Query to execute, and after the login Query is complete I want then loadfriendrequest Query to begin. Right now i am using NSTimer to solve it but that feels like a really bad solution!

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"friends")
query.whereKey("toUser", equalTo:"user.currentuser")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    // The find succeeded.
    print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) friendrequests.")
  //here i save some things in variables
    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
      for object in objects {
        print(object.objectId)
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
  }
}
```

if i want to after this Query is completed run Another Query i should be able to use completion right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursion mechanism when a function calls itself.
For example you have your method `requestData` where you make your querys:

```
func requestData(completion block: (data: [PFObject]) -> Void) {
   var query = PFQuery(className:"friends")
   query.whereKey("toUser", equalTo:"user.currentuser")
   query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
   (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
      // The find succeeded.
      print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) friendrequests.")
      //here i save some things in variables
      if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
          for object in objects {
            print(object.objectId)
          }
          // Here you can return data from closure
          block(objects)
      } else {
         // Log details of the failure
         print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
         block([])
      }
   }
}
```

And you have the method for calling `requestData`:

```
func requestAction() {
    requestData(completion: {(data: SomaType) -> Void in 
        // Some test to need next request
        // if self.requestIsNeeded() {
        //     self.requestAction()
        // }
        // Or loop the requests
        self.requestAction()
    })
}
```

And in your button action:

```
func buttonAction() {
    requestAction()
}
```

Comment: i am sure you are right but i can't really udnerstand how to put it into my code since i am beginner but i edited my post so you can see what i mean !

Comment: @Robinhiio I edit answer with added your code. But you put too little code, so it is not clear what is going on outside of your code that you posted. If you will have questions, write it here